# Python: Dynamically calculate rolling returns over different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Consider a DataFrame with multiple columns as follows:

```
data = [[99330,12,122],[1123,1230,1287],[123,101,812739],[1143,1230123,252],[234,342,4546],[2445,3453,3457],[7897,8657,5675],[46,5675,453],[76,484,3735],[363,93,4568],[385,568,367],[458,846,4847],[574,45747,658468],[57457,46534,4675]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
                       '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
                       '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12',
                       '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14'], 
          columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1: 
            col_A   col_B   col_C
2022-01-01  99330   12      122
2022-01-02  1123    1230    1287
2022-01-03  123     101     812739
2022-01-04  1143    1230123 252
2022-01-05  234     342     4546
2022-01-06  2445    3453    3457
2022-01-07  7897    8657    5675
2022-01-08  46      5675    453
2022-01-09  76      484     3735
2022-01-10  363     93      4568
2022-01-11  385     568     367
2022-01-12  458     846     4847
2022-01-13  574     45747   658468
2022-01-14  57457   46534   4675
```

Is there a way to write a loop so I can calculate the rolling returns on a daily ('1D'), weekly ('1W'), monthly ('1M') and six monthly ('6M') basis?

EDIT: Here is my attempt at calculating the rolling return on a daily and weekly basis:

```
periodicity_dict = {'1D':'daily', '1W':'weekly'}
df_columns = df1.columns
for key in periodicity_dict:
    for col in df_columns:
        df1[col+'_rolling']= np.nan
        for i in pd.date_range(start=df1[col].first_valid_index(), end=df1[col].last_valid_index(), freq=key):
                df1[col+'_rolling'].iloc[i] = (df1[col].iloc[i] - df[col].iloc[i-'1W'])/df[col].iloc[i-'1W']
```

Comment: You would like to calculate the sum of each column for those rolling windows?

Comment: No. just the return. So for example, a weekly return would be `(df1['col_A'].iloc[i] - df['col_A'].iloc[i-'1W'])/df['col_a'].iloc[i-'1W']`

Comment: You should add this description on the question because it is not yet clear how you would like to calculate your return. But it is still not clear to me.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) does the shifting math for you, but you would have to do it one window at a time.

```py
windows = ["1D", "7D"]
for window in windows:
    df1 = pd.merge(
        df1,
        (
            df1[["col_A", "col_B", "col_C"]]
            .pct_change(freq=window)
            .add_suffix(f"_rolling_{window}")
        ),
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to shift your index by a certain time period. For instance you can shift everything one day with:

```
df1.shift(freq="1D").add_suffix("_1D")
```

This will then be something like:

```
            col_A_1D  col_B_1D  col_C_1D
2022-01-02     99330        12       122
2022-01-03      1123      1230      1287
2022-01-04       123       101    812739
2022-01-05      1143   1230123       252
2022-01-06       234       342      4546
```

You can then add the new columns to the existing data:

```
df1.merge(df1.shift(freq="1D").add_suffix("_1D"), how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

```
            col_A    col_B   col_C  col_A_1D   col_B_1D  col_C_1D
2022-01-01  99330       12     122       NaN        NaN       NaN
2022-01-02   1123     1230    1287   99330.0       12.0     122.0
2022-01-03    123      101  812739    1123.0     1230.0    1287.0
2022-01-04   1143  1230123     252     123.0      101.0  812739.0
2022-01-05    234      342    4546    1143.0  1230123.0     252.0
```

And then just calculate e.g. `(df1["col_A"] - df1["col_A_1D"]) / df1["col_A_1D"]`. This will then result in:

```
2022-01-01          NaN
2022-01-02    -0.988694
2022-01-03    -0.890472
2022-01-04     8.292683
2022-01-05    -0.795276
```

You can do this for all the required columns and time shifts in the same way. For instance:

```
initial_cols = ["col_A", "col_B", "col_C"]
shifted_cols = [f"{c}_1D" for c in initial_cols]
for i, s in zip(initial_cols, shifted_cols):
    df1[f"{i}_rolling"] = (df1[i] - df1[s]) / df1[s]
```

This will then result in:

```
            col_A    col_B   col_C  col_A_1D   col_B_1D  col_C_1D  col_A_rolling  col_B_rolling  col_C_rolling
2022-01-01  99330       12     122       NaN        NaN       NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
2022-01-02   1123     1230    1287   99330.0       12.0     122.0      -0.988694     101.500000       9.549180
2022-01-03    123      101  812739    1123.0     1230.0    1287.0      -0.890472      -0.917886     630.498834
2022-01-04   1143  1230123     252     123.0      101.0  812739.0       8.292683   12178.435644      -0.999690
2022-01-05    234      342    4546    1143.0  1230123.0     252.0      -0.795276      -0.999722      17.039683
```

So to answer the main question:

```
Is there a way to write a loop so I can calculate the rolling returns on a daily ('1D'), weekly ('1W'), monthly ('1M') and six monthly ('6M') basis?
```

Yes, but there is also a way to do it without a loop :)